# Redirect out of a expect-spawned process to a log file

Tags: bash, expect

I have a script that spawns another process.
I want to redirect output of that process to a log file.
But >> doesnt work

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/usr/local/bin/expect -f
####echo $@
/usr/local/bin/expect <<EOD
set timeout 10
spawn $sec/add.zims.user ${1} "${2} ${3}" >> /home/arvind/logs/ADD.log
expect "e4234234's Password: " { send "${4}\n" }
expect "*'s New password: " { send "${5}\n" }
expect "Enter the new password again:" { send "${5}\n" }
EOD
```

'''

Comment: Why are you asking this as a bash question rather than an expect question? `spawn` is not part of bash, it's part of `expect` (a distinct, not-at-all-bash TCL-based language).

Comment: That said, what you're doing right here is using string substitution in bash to generate code that `expect` then parses and runs. That's generally a really, *really* bad idea; someone malicious could set a password of `"}; system("rm -rf ~"); #` or somesuch to make your TCL interpreter run evil code.

Comment: ...in general, instead of having *bash* substitute in `${1}`, `${2}`, etc. before TCL is started, you should have TCL itself reading the argument list, and not involve bash anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `spawn` command does not process shell redirections <sup>(1)</sup>

You could either let the shell handle the redirection:

```sh
/usr/local/bin/expect <<EOD
# ...
spawn ... ;# with no redirection
# ...
EOD
```

Or, use the expect `log_file` and `log_user` commands:

- `log_file -a $env(HOME)/logs/ADD.log` will send output into that log file (appending unless you specify the `-noappend` flag). This does **not** turn off regular output to stdout
- `log_user 0` will turn off the usual stdout output. This does not alter logging using `log_file`

So:

```sh
/usr/local/bin/expect <<EOD
set timeout 10
log_user 0
log_file -a /home/arvind/logs/ADD.log
spawn $sec/add.zims.user ${1} "${2} ${3}"
# ...
END
```

---

<sup>(1) -- the `exec` command *does* do redirections, but not exactly like the shell: see [the `exec` manual](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/exec.htm)</sup>